# Cherry pick peers using Rasterbar libtorrent in Python

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

Does anyone know if it's possible to cherry pick peers to connect with using libtorrent? That is, after the tracker returns a list of peer IPs and ports, only a selected few will be connected with based on some defined criteria.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can remove peers from the set using [set_ip_filter()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Session.html#set_ip_filter()). you can add peers to the set by using [connect_peer()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#connect_peer()). That's about all the control you have. The priority of which peers from the set to connect to in which order is hard coded.

Comment: connect_peer was moved to http://libtorrent.org/reference-Torrent_Handle.html#connect-peer