# Libtorrent add peer by IP

Tags: c++, ip-address, p2p, dht, libtorrent

Is there a straightforward way to manually add a peer by IP address using Libtorrent? For example, if you already have the IP address of a peer that has the requested file and want to add them to the peer list.

Comment: Did you make an attempt? Can you show us your research? With what, specifically, are you having difficulty?

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure this isn't how it works. If someone's seeding a torrent then they will already be in the peer list. You can't "add" a peer that isn't already a peer. I see nothing in [the documentation](http://www.libtorrent.org/reference.html) to suggest that what you're asking can (or should) be done. Why not just download from the other peers?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I looked through the libtorrent documentation and wasn't able to find anything. Ideally I'd want a fast means to verify whether or not a given peer is connected to the network and seeding a file. If we already happen to know their IP address,we could just add them to the peer list directly (given that they are seeding the file and are connected to the network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't yet tried it, but I'm pretty sure the [connect_peer](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#connect_peer()) function should do the trick:

```
void connect_peer (tcp::endpoint const& adr, int source = 0
  , int flags = 0x1 + 0x4 + 0x8) const;
```

> connect_peer() is a way to manually connect to peers that one believe is a part of the torrent. If the peer does not respond, or is not a member of this torrent, it will simply be disconnected. No harm can be done by using this other than an unnecessary connection attempt is made. If the torrent is uninitialized or in queued or checking mode, this will throw libtorrent_exception. The second (optional) argument will be bitwised ORed into the source mask of this peer. Typically this is one of the source flags in peer_info. i.e. tracker, pex, dht etc.
>
> flags are the same flags that are passed along with the ut_pex extension.

Comment: Arvid Norberg agrees [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26902087/751579).

Comment: connect_peer was moved to http://libtorrent.org/reference-Torrent_Handle.html#connect-peer